# JQuery .append of a </select> tag ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id='show-label'>
  <select id="comboboxShowLabel">
    <option value="">Hide or show labels?</option>
    <option value="Show Labels">Show Label</option> 
    <option value="Hide Labels">Hide Label</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want to add the the `<select></select>` to the parent div at runtime, ala:

```
     <div id='show-label'>
     </div>

    $("#show-label").html("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'>")
        .append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
        .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
        .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>")
        .append("</select>");
```

For resons unknown to me, the closing  tag isn't getting injected into the page.

I've tried the code above as well as something like this:

```
.append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option></select>")
```

Is there some sort requirement around "batching" these elements into a single .append? I'm wondering if this approach doesn't seem well-formed when it's loading into the DOM, so it's ignored...

Thanks!

Comment: you ***can't*** attach incomplete elements to the dom. get rid of all the appends and do it in one sweeping action.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Was trying to be too fancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#show-label").append(function() {
    return $("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'>")
        .append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
        .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
        .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`append()` only appends one element to an other element. What you need to do is to make a valid select tag. You can then append the options to that. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#show-label").html("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'></select>")
$('#show-label select').append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
    .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
    .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
var $select = $("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'></select>");
$("#show-label").html($select);
$select.append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
    .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
    .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>");
```

if you need to append afterward for whatever reason. Otherwise do it this way for better browser efficiency (one change to the actual dom rather than multiple):

```
var $select = $("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'></select>")
    .append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
    .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
    .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>");
$("#show-label").html($select);
```

Comment: it would be more efficient to append the options to the select before appending the select to the label.

Comment: @KevinB, I was going to do it that way but I figure there might be stuff in between the appends or something in the OP's actual implementation... I've put up both ways now.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$("#show-label").html("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'>")
```

sets the html of `#show-label`, and returns a jQuery object representing `#show-label`. The second part is important there, because it means your next line,

```
.append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
```

is also appended to `#show-label`, which isn't what you want. Try this:

```
$("#show-label").empty().append(
    $('<select/>')
        .append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
        .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
        .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply append the completed select and then add the options to it:

```
$("#show-label").html("<select id='comboboxShowLabel'></select");
$("#comboboxShowLabel")
    .append("<option value=''>Hide or show labels?</option>")
    .append("<option value='Show Labels'>Show Label</option>")
    .append("<option value='Hide Labels'>Hide Label</option>");
```